# Can I edit a file on an asp.net core web app?

Tags: c#, html, file, asp.net-core, razor

Is it possible to edit a file in asp.net core. I am making a website that if you press the button, it will add or delete something from a file. I'v tried using react but I don't like it and it didn't do what I expected it to do. Please help me I don't want to make like 400 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can edit file using asp.net.
It's worth to understand that you cannot change the file stored on client side, but you still can create/edit/delete files stored

1. on your web app host
2. any other remote storage via API (for example Azure Storage or any S3-like storage)

Comment: Aw man, I wish I could well oh well Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: In that case you could modify file on backend and then prompt user to download result file. Another way is using js or web assembly to access files but it requires users permissions